# How to know a widget called from?

Tags: flutter

### Files

input_email_widget.dart

```
class InputEmail {
 return TextFormField();
}
```

input_password_widget.dart

```
class InputPassword {
 return TextFormField();
}
```

sign_up_page.dart

```
class SignUpPage {
 return Form {
  InputEmail();
  InputPassword();
 }
}
```

login_page.dart

```
class LoginPage {
 return Form {
  InputEmail();
  InputPassword();
 }
}
```

### Question

How to know the InputEmail textformfield widget is called from sign up page or login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that you need to know where the widget is. TextFormField have a textEdittingController that contains the value of text. And you probably will use this value in a widget that is the parent of TextFormField, so probably you don't need to know where the TextFormField is

you may do something like that

```
class InputEmail{
 InputEmail(textEditingController controller){
   return TextFormField(
    ...// decorate your widget
   controller:controller
   }
 }
}
class LoginPage {
 textEditingController emailController = textEditingController()
 textEditingController passwordController = textEditingController()
 void buttonFunction(){
   var email=emailController.text
   var password=passwordController.text
   do_login(email,password)
 }
 return Form {
  InputEmail(controller);
  InputPassword(controller);
  Button(onPressed:buttonFunction)

 }
}
```

Comment: I understand what do you mean. But its not what i ask. Let i take the example based on your code. When login page return a form that call InputEmail(controller), InputEmail widget is owned by login page right? But, how if sign up page return a form that call InputEmail(controller) too? How i know InputEmail widget called by login page and called by sign up page?

Comment: Btw thank you, your answer make me found another way for overcome my problem

Comment: If you  want to know what widget call the inputEmail you need to pass another variable on the builder of inputEmail like String origin.